# How to solve error: ';' expected in Java?

Tags: java

I have a `error: ';' expected` issue with my Java code below. I don't know how to solve it?

`SortThread` and `MergeThread` have been created as a class, and compiled well.

The only problem is

```
SortThread t1.join() = new SortThread(a);  
SortThread t2.join() = new SortThread(b);  

MergeThread m.start() = new MergeThread(t1.get(),t2.get());
```

These three line codes has `error: ';' expected` issues.

In this main, it will create two array, a and b.
m array will merge a&b, and main will display m.

Any hints or solutions are very helpful for me.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

int n = r.nextInt(101) + 50;
int[] a = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  a[i] = r.nextInt(100);

n = r.nextInt(101) + 50;
int[] b = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  b[i] = r.nextInt(100);

SortThread t1.join() = new SortThread(a);  
SortThread t2.join() = new SortThread(b);  

MergeThread m.start() = new MergeThread(t1.get(),t2.get());

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.get()));
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to provide a seed like this, the built in one is better.

Comment: I can't see the problem, start commenting lines out from the bottom until the problem goes away. Then you know that line is causing the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call the methods before you finish initializing the variables you're calling.

```
SortThread t1.join() = new SortThread(a);  
SortThread t2.join() = new SortThread(b);  

MergeThread m.start() = new MergeThread(t1.get(),t2.get());
```

should be something like

```
SortThread t1 = new SortThread(a);  
t1.start(); // <-- you probably want to start before you join.
SortThread t2 = new SortThread(b);
t2.start();  
t1.join();
t2.join();
MergeThread m = new MergeThread(t1.get(),t2.get());
m.start();
m.join();
```

Comment: for `start()` and `join()`, compiler says `error: cannot find symbol`